# Custom background image, how do I get the file path and set it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I want a user to be able to change the BODY background image.

At the moment I am using a INPUT of type FILE. I was trying a plain text input before and that worked for images uploaded to the web but I couldn't seem to get it to work for local files

```
<input id='img_url' type='file' accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

When I console log $(img_url).val(), I get

```
C:\fakepath\imageName.png
```

not an actual directory to the file.

Will the user have to upload the image to my server?

Comment: Yes, user must upload image before using it as background image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom things such as display names or pictures would usually be something either stored as a database value or on the web server in the project's directory. That then gets loaded on page load.

Comment: Ah ok, I was wondering if there was a way to load a local image file without having to transfer file to a webserver.